# Android: Applying MVVM the correct way (Part II)

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, mutation-observers

Again, if anyone consider it off-topic let me know and I'll immediately delete the question.

I'm still learning (and very interested in) how to migrate my app to MVVM, and trying to do my best in it, but I'm still having silly doubts.

Let's talk about one of them, for example:

As far as I understand, in ViewModel you should put all bussiness logic, what is not related to the view itself, so...

Given the next small method:

```
private void finishTest()
{
    int totalAnsweredQuestions = testViewModel.getTotalAnsweredQuestions(oTest);
    if (totalAnsweredQuestions != oTest.getQuestions().size()) {
        leaveTest(Enum.LeaveTestSource.FINISHTESTBUTTON);
    } else {
        showGeneratingResultsGif();
    }
}
```

We could say that

```
if (totalAnsweredQuestions != oTest.getQuestions().size())
```

is bussiness logic, but as the method is too short does it really worth to move this one line to a ViewModel method given that maybe is more the refactoring it implies than the real benefits? Or maybe given the method and logic is too simple is better just to leave it into the activity?

To be more clear:

I could move the above method to ViewModel the next way:

```
private void finishTest(TestDTO test)
{
    int totalAnsweredQuestions = getTotalAnsweredQuestions(test);
    if (totalAnsweredQuestions != test.getQuestions().size()) {
        testResult.setValue(new Pair<>("", Enum.TestResult.LEAVETEST));
    } else {
        testResult.setValue(new Pair<>("", Enum.TestResult.SHOWGENERATINGRESULTS));
    }
}
```

And then in the activity's observer according to the enum do a

```
leaveTest(Enum.LeaveTestSource.FINISHTESTBUTTON);
```

or

```
showGeneratingResultsGif();
```

But I'm not sure it has sense when we are talking of only one if.

Comment: you're getting caught up by small and trivial issues, over-complicating an issue which doesn't really exist. there is no law which says that a viewmodel should _always_ be making use of live data to return results, so these methods can just be normal return statements, which could return true or false without live data. if you want to follow a _reactive_ pattern, sure, you could consider doing this. also, the length of code isn't what determines where it should go. assigning text to a button also isn't a lot of code, does that mean i can put it in my repository ?

Comment: In short, the view (Activity/Fragment) should not do any thing by it self, to perform any thing, it should call ViewModels's method/variable, and then viewModel will perform task, and if any thing changes, view which is already listening to the changes via LiveData/Flow etc, will get notified.

Comment: And to do only UI updation, view should be responsible

Comment: Thank you very much for your input @a_local_nobody. It's really helpful to me, and I'll surely follow your guidelines :)

Comment: Thank you @NehaK, the same as a_local_nobody, I appreciate your time and follow your guidelines :)

Comment: My answer is based on real-world projects, as 7+ years experienced android developer, the answer I gave works almost on every project and make code usability and debugging very easy. This is called good programming skills.